# Php Application Form - Unique E-mail Error

Tags: php, forms

I am creating an application form on a commercial website. The applications need to be sent to an e-mail address with two extensions (unsure of proper term:  .ns.ca) example Admin@halifaxwildlife.ns.ca.

My php present no log errors, and in texting the submitter does recieve the confirmation e-mail and the above e-mail shows up in the TO: field. However that e-mail never gets recieved.

When I change the TO: e-mail so something with just a .com or .ca extension the form works just fine.

How can I setup up my server or php to accommodate this unique e-mail address?

```
<?php
    // Fetching Values from URL.
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname1'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname1'];
    $address = $_POST['address1'];
    $email = $_POST['email1'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone1'];
    $regular = $_POST['regular1'];
    $family = $_POST['family1'];
    $crest = $_POST['crest1'];


    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); // Sanitizing E-mail.

// After sanitization Validation is performed
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{10}$/", $phone)) {
        echo "<span>* Please Fill Valid Contact No. *</span>";
        } else {
        $subject = $firstname + $lastname + "HWA Application";
        // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set.
        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From:' . $email. "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
        $headers .= 'Cc:' . $email. "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
        $template = '<div style="padding:50px; color:white;">Hello ' . $firstname . $lastname . ',<br/>'
        . '<br/>Thank you...! For Contacting Us.<br/><br/>'
        . 'Name:' . $firstname + $lastname . '<br/>'
        . 'Address:' . $address . '<br/>'
        . 'Email:' . $email . '<br/>'
        . 'This is a Contact Confirmation mail.'
        . '<br/>'
        . 'We Will contact You as soon as possible .</div>';
        $sendmessage = "<div style=\"background-color:#7E7E7E; color:white;\">" . $template . "</div>";
        // Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it.
        $sendmessage = wordwrap($sendmessage, 70);
        // Send mail by PHP Mail Function.
        mail("admin@HalifaxWidlife.ns.ca", $subject, $sendmessage, $headers);
        echo "Your Query has been received, We will contact you soon.";
        }
        } else {
        echo "<span>* invalid email *</span>";
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: You're probably dealing with the filter_vars looking at the email address, and passing back 'false'.  Test it using "print_r($email)" and seeing what the output is.  if it's "false" then the filter is to blame.  Email filtering is a complicated thing, and badly implemented almost everywhere.  I would really consider if you 'actually' need to make sure the email is valid?  Or is emailing that invalid email address enough of a test?

Comment: Recommended reading:  Email validation with REGEX http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: I don't think I am validating the To: email which is my concerned e-mail at the moment. There are people with e-mails like this so I will remove the validator as we don't need to get that complex. 

However, I am hardcoding in the receivers e-mail address, I don't see any validation.
`mail("admin@HalifaxWidlife.ns.ca", $subject, $sendmessage, $headers);`

As said, the form works great, but that To: email will never receive this. If I use "Info@Alliemunro.com" it will work just fine. Ideas?

Comment: Hey have you tested that sending does not work?  You do need to configure your SMTP server, which is a whole nother topic better suited for 'Server' stackexchange.  You would want to check the /var/log/mail.log for your server to see 'why' its failing to send.  Sorry not much help but hopefully this gets you in the right area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a zone file issue with GoDaddy. To complex of an issue for them to handle. I ended creating a separate e-mail account with gmail that auto forwarded any applications to the correct e-mail. No ideal but this works just fine.